# Cannot create a new build agent with team foundation server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild, build-agent

We recently upgraded to team foundation server 2012 update 2 and now we are getting a error when ever we try to add a new build agent.

Error:
TF900559: Build agent MyBuildAgent cannot serve build controller MyBuildControler. The build controller and agent must run the same version of Team Foundation Build.

Now I have made sure that we are running the correct versions  and have even tried it with a fresh install, with update 1, and update 2 and I still receive this error message.

I should note that this build agent was created by making a copy of another agent we have and renaming everything.

Has any one had an issue like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user2291942

I was receiving this error when I was trying to integrate TFS 2012 Update 2 with TFS 2010 build servers.  I knew that 2012 Update 2 was designed to allow this, but I had configured the controller on the Application Tier Server (as I think many people do), which is obviously running TFS 2012 Update 2.

To correct this, I configured a TFS 2010 server as a build controller that connects to the TFS 2012 Update 2 Application Tier / Repository.  Then, when creating build agents and attaching them to that controller, the issue was resolved.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you have upgraded to TFS 2012 Update 2 on the TFS App Server + Build Controller + Build Agent?

Failing that I would suggest just uninstalling TFS and re-installing TFS on the build agent server.  This is a relatively quick and painless process.